# How to delete from multiple tables in database using left join

Tags: sql, mysqli

I store different data in 4 different tables. and want to delete data from all the tables in one query. and also some datas, that is available in tblapps,  can't be in other tables, so wanted to use left join. tried this but got error-

```
    DELETE * from tblapps 
LEFT JOIN tblapps2 ON tblapps.app_id = tblapps2.app_id 
LEFT JOIN tblapps3 ON tblapps.app_id = tblapps3.app_id 
LEFT JOIN payments ON tblapps.app_id = payments.app_id 
WHERE 
tblapps.app_id = 'EVISA2505545524'
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from tblapps LEFT JOIN tblapps2 ON tblapps.app_id = tblapps2.app_id LEFT JOIN ' at line 1**

Comment: Tip: Check out foreign keys with on delete cascade!

Comment: Or, to be safe, use 4 queries and write them in the proper order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the bellow script

```
DELETE tblapps,
  tblapps2,
  tblapps3,
  payments
FROM tblapps
LEFT JOIN tblapps2
ON tblapps.app_id = tblapps2.app_id
LEFT JOIN tblapps3
ON tblapps.app_id = tblapps3.app_id
LEFT JOIN payments
ON tblapps.app_id    = payments.app_id
WHERE tblapps.app_id = 'EVISA2505545524'
```